# Is report server 2019 not available

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2017

I tried to find SSRS Reporting Services 2019. Has MS stopped this?

If not, could anyone please provide the link to download this?

Note: somehow I'm unable to install Reporting Services 2017, showing error during installation. That's why I'm trying to use any newer version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to SQL Server Reporting Services Design tools for Visual Studio 2019, you can download it from the following link:

- [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio)

If you need the SQL Server Reporting Services 2019 (SQL Server 2019), it is not released yet. Referring to the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/what-s-new-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-2019-preview-reporting-services):

> SQL Server 2019 preview Reporting Services isn't available for CTP 3.0. Install the current version, [SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services 2019- When this will be released? Lets say, if someone has developed a report in SSDT 2019, which version report server he/she has to refer to deply this?

Comment: @AskMe i think it will be released after SQL Servee 2019 is released since it is now a preview version.

Comment: @AskMe you can set the SQL Server version using the `TargetServerVersion` property : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/set-deployment-properties-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

As of now, 2017 is the latest version of SSRS. As to whether or not Microsoft have stopped development, that is unlikely but there is no official announcements to this effect.

Comment: Can somehow Power BI report server be used to host SSRS 2017 report. If yes, How? Which tools needed and how to host that? Any tutorial or link please?

Comment: No.  You need to host your SSRS reports within an SSRS Report Server.  They can then be pinned to Power BI dashboards to be shown alongside.